# How to add element inside this interface NameValuePair?

Tags: angular, typescript

MY INTERFACE:-

```
export interface NameValuePair {
    name: string;
    value: string;
}
```

USE:-

```
isModerator: NameValuePair[] = [];
```

I want to add two element 1) name: 'YES' value: 'Y'
2) name: 'NO' value: 'N' inside isModerator which is of type NameValuePair array.
it's My TypeScript file

Comment: `isModerator: NameValuePair[] = [{ name: 'YES', value: 'Y' }, { name: 'NO', value: 'N' }];` or use [`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the push method:

```
isModerator.push({name: 'YES', value: 'Y'});
isModerator.push({name: 'NO', value: 'N'});
```